# Merge dictionary values into a set

Tags: python, python-2.6

How do I do the following in the form of a oneliner:

```
replacements = set()
for i in replacement_per_file.values():
    replacements.update(i)
```

Comment: i variable is a list?

Comment: `replacement_per_file.values()` This looks more like a dictionary than a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
replacements = set(x for i in replacement_per_file.values() for x in i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `i` is a list (or `iterable`), then you're looking for this:

```
replacements = set([
    x
    for i in replacement_per_file.values()
    for x in i
])
```

Answer (score 0):

An `itertools` version inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
>>> set(chain(*a))
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
set().union(replacement_per_file.values())
```

This is slightly less efficient than your multi-line way, as it requires creating a copy of value references for the arguments of `union`.